# Client side modal login possible with IdentityServer3? Which Flow?

Tags: authentication, identityserver3

I've been task with replacing a custom login system to now use IdentityServer3.
The requirement is to have a client side modal popup - very similar to what AuthO ha (picture below)

(we are not using Auth0 though but it is obviously a brilliant product)

So we'll still have our own database (which we fully control), as well as allowing 3rd party login.

My questions:

1. Will a client side modal login be possible? In the examples the login is always redirected to the actual OAuth server.
   Can you please give me ideas on where/what I should be investigating?
2. Which Flow should I be looking at? It looks like Resource Owner flow, is this correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the username/password entry in the client application, you have to use resource owner flow. There are a couple of drawbacks - check this video

https://vimeo.com/171942749

(and the spec that is discussed there)

Also Auth0 must do a redirect for Google etc - that's how the model works. Resource owner is mostly for legacy.